# First slider image not showing on second loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

A jquery slider I've been working on works fine when it loops through the first four pictures. Although, when it hits the first picture a second time, the first slide is blank, but all other slides show up perfectly fine. I've tried changing the sliderIndex and sliderNext variables to no avail as well.

Slider Looping Function Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider() {
count = $("#slider-images img").size();
sliderIndex = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

loop = setInterval(function() {

    if(sliderNext > count){
        sliderNext = 1;
        sliderIndex = 1;
    }

    slideOut("#slider-images img", "left");
    slideIn("img#slide-" + sliderNext, "right");

    sliderIndex = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 6000);
}
```

HTML for slider:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img id="previous" src="img/previous.png" alt="" />
    <img id="next" src="img/next.png" alt="" />

    <div id="slider-images">
        <img id="slide-1 "src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img id="slide-2" src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="" />
        <img id="slide-3" src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img id="slide-4" src="img/slide-4.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Slider CSS:

```
#slider {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}

#slider-images {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pasted code matches your actual code, the id for slide-1 has a space in it, so your code isn't finding it.

```
<img id="slide-1 " ...
```

Comment: @JacobGreenway Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes. ;)